# What is W.Image created by javascript in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, browser, webkit

I found a strange image prototype when I debugged my project in Google Chrome.
The image prototype like this:
[strange image prototype picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyNKJ.png)
The image object is only made by new Image().The HTMLImageElement prototype is right in usual we think.
So what is W.Image?A new image prototype or a Google Chrome bug?